# C- - how to perform a function on all files in directory?

Tags: c, function, file, iteration

I am trying to perform a function (`void action(const char*)`) on all files in a specific directory (i dont know their names). what is the easiest way to do it?
im not very good in C and i found some very helpful code in other users questions but i did not succeed in making it work for me with this input (did not find how to find all file names in the directory for the function)

thanks.

Comment: Most important question is, why do you want to do that? Your question lacks the appropriate context, acheiving this with a c program can be hard to make portable and you need to explain why do you need a c program for this. Perhaps a library that you're using, something ... ???

Comment: Read the documentation for `opendir` and `readdir`

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=c++find+all+file+names+in+the+directory

Comment: thanks! i think i got it but im having problems with finding the directory. I am using ubuntu am i want to direct it to a folder called "my" on my desktop.
what char* should i give to the opendir function?
 thanks.

Comment: There isn't a way built into C; this is operating-system-specific.

Answer (score 0):

A fairly painless solution if you are able/willing to use `find` and `xargs`. Not the fastest, but a good balance between ease of development and performance if you do not have too many files. You can do something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void handle_file(char* fname)
{
  FILE* fp = fopen(fname,"r");
  // deal with fp == NULL - do you want to abort or ignore if a file cannot be processed?
  // do your magic with fp
  fclose(fp);
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  int i;
  for (i = 1; i < argc; i++)
    handle_file(fname);
  return 0;
}
```

compile this into a binary, let's call it `do_file_magic`.

then from Bash:

`find . -type f -print0 | xargs -0 ./do_file_magic`

or

`find . -type -f -exec ./do_file_magic {] \;`

Comment: Its an exercise and i need to build a single c file that performs a function on all of the files in a gives path. do you know how to do it only in C code? thanks.

Comment: As was suggested, read the manual on opendir()/readdir(), find examples, and use recursion - see example at http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Walk_a_directory/Recursively#Library:_POSIX